# Tomcat and logback.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, logback

I am starting up a `Seam + Hibernate + Logback` project deployed to `Tomcat 6`. I use Eclipse as an `IDE`. Hibernate prints many debug statements, so I have put the level to `ERROR`, so I don't see them.

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="ERROR" />
</logger>
```

I don't paste my whole `logback.xml`, because the problem I have, is not connected with its contents.

I have the following classpath problem - If I put the `logback.xml` in `WEB-INF\classes`of my project, it is not found by the classloader and I see all debug statements. On the other hand, if I move the `logback.xml` to the `lib` directory of `Tomcat`, everything works perfect and the debug statements are not printed.

But I want to have my `logback.xml` inside my project, not in the root `lib` directory of Tomcat.

**And here is my question - isn't the `WEB-INF\classes` a correct place for `logback.xml`? Why isn't it found?**

I have always known that the files under the `WEB-INF\classes` directory of the project, are put to the classpath. Thank you for any ideas you have.

All the best, Petar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like your `logback.jar` is also under `${catalina.home}\lib`.

If you want to put your `logback.xml` to `\WEB-INF\classes`, the `logback.jar` should be only under `\WEB-INF\lib`. The `${catalina.home}\lib\logback.jar` should be removed.

Comment: Thanks:) This was the case - I have forgot to remove it from ${catalina.home}\lib.