# Logback Not working in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, configuration, logback

I am using Tomcat 7 and have configured the shared library path using shared.loader property in catalina file. Now I have a web application which doesn t contain any libraries within the /WEB-INF/lib as i have a shared folder in tomcat for all the dependencies.

Problem :

My application always takes Basic Logback configurator rather than using the config file which i have given inside application's /WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml. How to make Logback load the config file which is inside the /WEB-INF/classes directory.

Findings :

I have checked the stack overflow and got a similar issue,

[Tomcat and logback.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078842/tomcat-and-logback-xml?rq=1)

but the solution they gave is to move the logback.jar file to /WEB-INF/lib folder of web application and logback.xml will be identified, which even worked for me. But I don t want to move the libararies to web application instead I want to have it in Tomcat Shared folder.

So Kindly let me know how I can make logback find the config file within /WEB-INF/classes directory and have my logback dependencies located in Tomcat shared folder.

Thanks,
Prasanna Venkataraman.

Comment: The manual says you can specify the class path via a system property: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html 
 But, I don't know if that would work since the WEB-INF/classes may not exist when Tomcat starts. At any rate, it is messy: in theory, you have one Tomcat and multiple webapps, each with its own logback config.